# breadcrumbs_on_rails missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement breadcrumbs via breadcrumbs_on_rails gem. So far so good, works with the home page and the `index` page, but I'm having trouble implementing crumbs on the `show` page. Getting the error:

**ERROR: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects"}, missing required keys: [:id]**

Here's what the controller looks like:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
...
  add_breadcrumb "home", :root_path
  add_breadcrumb "properties", :projects_path
  add_breadcrumb "show", :project_path
...
  def index 
     add_breadcrumb "properties", projects_path
  end
...
  def show
    @developer = @project.developer
    @description = @project.description
    add_breadcrumb "show", project_property_path, @project_id
    #add_breadcrumb "show", projects_path
    #add_breadcrumb "Debt #{@project.id}", project_path(@project.id)
  end
```

I've commented out those other two lines in `def show` as they didn't seem to work.

I've also got `<%= render_breadcrumbs %>` in my application header, which was working fine until I tried to implement the `show` crumb.

Any suggestions? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try removing the `add_breadcrumb "show", :project_path` at the top? The project path requires the id of the specific project, which is not provided there.

Comment: Sure thing! So I've edited it on your recommendations, now it's pointing to the add_breadcrumb within the show action, getting the `missing required keys: [:project_id]` still. Maybe it's my syntax, how should I be calling on the project id?

Comment: @Anuj I just edited again, and it's working! Thanks very much for your help, I'll post up an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turned out I just needed to remove

```
add_breadcrumb "show", :project_path
```

from the top, as per Anuj's suggestion, then just move

```
add_breadcrumb "properties", :projects_path
```

to the `show` action in order to remove duplicates and make it clean. The result is as follows:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
 ...
  add_breadcrumb "Home ", :root_path
...
 def index 
  add_breadcrumb "Properties", projects_path
 end
...
 def show
  @developer = @project.developer
  @description = @project.description
  add_breadcrumb "Properties", projects_path
  add_breadcrumb "#{@project.name}", project_property_path(@project)
 end
```

Happy days!